# Is this possible to edit the Unity app through inspector while running on Android device?

Tags: unity, android, debugging

When on PC, I can run the app and edit things temporarily through the `inspector`.

I know that I can attach the `Android ADB` and the profiler, but is there any option to edit objects through the inspector while running on the emulator/physical device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

And it is doubtful it ever will be supported. You need to rebuild to put it on the physical device, and you cannot realistically rebuild after every time you change a variable.

Try using Unity Remote, an app for running directly on your device without building. They might support it.

Comment: Yep, found Unity Remote, but it's just sending the PC graphical state, which is good for checking the UI placement, but not physics and lighting, which behave different on the mobile. If you are 100% sure it's not possible, I'll accept in a minute ;)

Comment: I am 100% sure. Sorry!